# Trying to convert string format (dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss) in (yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss) date format

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

I am capturing date from oracle in a string variable in this format
`string val1 = "30-03-2019 16:42:58"`  and trying to store it in sql database in (datetime) format eg `val2 = "2019-03-03 16:42:58.000"`

Storing date from oracle db in string variable

```
string val2 = row["t_in_o"].ToString();
```

and inserting in sql like

```
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@t_in_s",val2);
```

Expected

```
string val2="30-03-2019 16:42:58"
```

string variable val2 should be stored in
date variable date_V as `date_V="2019-03-03 16:42:58.000"`

Error message
The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: Why are you passing the data through C#?  It sounds like both operations should be a single SQL statement.

Comment: @GordonLinoff actually my req is to take value from oracle db and store it in sql db and it is schedule in every 5 minutes

Comment: what are the column types in oracle and sql server?

Comment: @sidprashar it is of type datetime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to first convert your date string to datetime.

```
string val2= row["t_in_o"].ToString(); 
Datetime date = DateTime.Parse(val2);

myCommand.Parameters.Add("@t_in_s", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = date;
```

Answer (score 1):

Oracle dates don't really have a format.

If you want to stor a string in the DB, just tell oracle it's a date with `to_date`

```
insert into Mytable (thedate)
values 
(to_date(:stringval1, 'DD-MM-YY HH24:MI:SS'))
```

Comment: This is the way to do it in Oracle, if you don't  want to do it in C# first. Side note: Oracle dates _do_ have a format if you use a [date literal expression](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm#BABGIGCJ) in the form of `values (date '2019-03-30')`. But this notation only supports date, not time.

Answer (score -1):

At first note that you trying to store value with milliseconds to you SQL Database but you haven't it in string that you getting from oracle (due to post summary), so it will be always .000.

But the this that you are asking can be done using following code:

```
    string val2 = DateTime.ParseExact(row["t_in_o"].ToString(), "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss", 
                                        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                                        .ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff");
```

Note that i didn't knew in what type you storing value in `row["t_in_o"]` so i counted it as `string`, if you converted this value to `DateTime` already just remove useless `Convert.ToDataTime` and use `row["t_in_o"].ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff");`

Comment: Also, the `date` type in Oracle doesn't have millisecond resolution. You'd need `timestamp` for that. But reading the question, I doubt if this is a requirement.

Comment: @GolezTrol in this case it really strange, if you don't have milliseconds in Ocarcle you shouldn't paste them to SQL, let SQL handle them by itself by adding .000 if it needed. Or change type of column and use `timestamp`. Also in SQL `date` type also don't have milliseconds (it don't have even hours) so this also need to be changed to `datetime`

Comment: I think you're mixing things up. Oracle has a date type which represents a date + time, up to 1 second accuracy. There is no datetime type for columns.

Comment: About `datetime` type of column i was talking about SQL

Comment: SQL is just a standard. It depends on specific implementation. In this case, it's about Oracle, which doesn't have a datetime type, only a date type, which in reality can also contain a time part. And in standard SQL there are different date and time related types, [but still no `datetime`](https://www.w3resource.com/sql/data-type.php#DATETIME).

Comment: Thanks, I really was mixing things up. When I was talking about SQL I was mean MS SQL/MySQL not the standard. Thanks for explanation